# Wait for all the threads to finish their job and then measure the time elapsed

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am using `Executor service` in one of my `Multithreaded code`. I am trying to see whether all of my threads are finished doing their job then afterwards I need to do certain task.

Currently I need to measure the time elapsed, so I can only measure the time elapsed only after all the threads has finished executing there job. So I have this code currently? And I am measuring `time elapsed` in the `finally block`.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);

long startTime = System.nanoTime();
try {
    for (int i = 0; i<noOfThreads; i++) {
        service.submit(new Task());
    }
    service.shutdown();
    service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Do I need this while block here?
    while (!service.isTerminated()) {

    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //Log exception here
} finally {
    long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    logTimingInfo(estimatedTime, noOfTasks, noOfThreads);
}
```

I am not sure whether I need `while loop` here or not? Is the way I am currently doing it right or not?

**Updated Code:-**

So below code should work fine. Right?

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noOfThreads);

long startTime = System.nanoTime();
try {
    for (int i = 0; i<noOfThreads; i++) {
        service.submit(new Task());
    }
    service.shutdown();
    service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);     
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    //Log exception here
} finally {
    long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: Do you need the `while`?  A: No.

The previous `awaitTermination` call won't return until either the service has terminated, or `(2^63 - 1)` seconds have elapsed.  (That is a *very* long time.)

---

**UPDATE** - The updated version looks OK to me.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the suggestion. So that means I won't be needing while loop right? And I can measure the time elapsed in the finally block then?

Comment: You don't really need a finally either.  You are only going to get an `InterruptedException` if some other thread interrupts the current one.  In that case, I hardly think you care what the timing was ... 'cos it won't be a meaningful measure of anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are not required to re-invent the wheel. You can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html

This works pretty fine. This should solve your problem statement too.